# Split up quantities to print labels

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an order sheet and a sheet dedicated to printing labels for items ordered.

The order sheet has three columns: qtyordered, packaging and item.

When someone orders more than one case of something, I need more than one label.

I’m looking for a way to split the value in qtyordered column into individual rows that will repeat as many times as necessary.

| qtyordered | packaging | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.5 | box | apples |

should become:

| qtyordered | packaging | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 0.5 | box | apples |

All in consecutive rows.

I don't know how to pull this off in Excel with either functions or macros.
I could use office scripts and handle it like I would in JavaScript; however, I don’t think this company has an up-to-date version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

**Contents of the "order" sheet, (range A1:C6):**

| qtyordered | packaging | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3,5 | box | apples |
| 5 | sack | plums |
| 0 | error | error |
| 1 | none | pinapples |
| 3 | wheelbarrow | melons |

**code:**

```vb
Sub expandData2()
    Dim rng As Range, arr() As Variant, targetCell As Range, splitSize As Double
    
    'targetCell is where the result will start being written
    Set targetCell = Worksheets("label").Range("A2")
    splitSize = 1
    
    'clear the previous labels, if there are any
    With Worksheets("label")
        If .Range("C2").Value <> "" Then
            .Range("A2:C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
        End If
    End With
    
    'find the last row on the "order" sheet, assign the range with the order to the arr array
    With Worksheets("order")
        Set rng = .Range("A2:C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    arr = rng
    
    Dim quantity As Double, packaging As String, item As String, rowCounter
    'loop through all rows of the order
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        quantity = arr(i, 1)
        packaging = arr(i, 2)
        item = arr(i, 3)
        'while quantity is larger than 0, subtract splitSize from it and create new label row
        Do While quantity > 0
            quantity = quantity - splitSize
            If quantity < 0 Then
                targetCell.Offset(rowCounter, 0) = quantity + splitSize
            Else
                targetCell.Offset(rowCounter, 0) = splitSize
            End If
            targetCell.Offset(rowCounter, 1) = packaging
            targetCell.Offset(rowCounter, 2) = item
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Result on "label" sheet:**

| qtyordered | packaging | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 1 | box | apples |
| 0,5 | box | apples |
| 1 | sack | plums |
| 1 | sack | plums |
| 1 | sack | plums |
| 1 | sack | plums |
| 1 | sack | plums |
| 1 | none | pinapples |
| 1 | wheelbarrow | melons |
| 1 | wheelbarrow | melons |
| 1 | wheelbarrow | melons |